# Не работает autoplay video на iphone в 2020

Tags: jquery, html5, видео

Здравствуйте уважаемые разработчики. Столкнулся с банальной задачей, автоматически запустить видео на ***iphone***. Вписал нужные атрибуты в тег `video:`
Также с помощью jquery пытаюсь включить видео:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('video')[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Пробовал обратиться по `id`, но проблему не решил. Использовал этот код пару месяцев назад всё работало. Но за это время видимо что то изменилось. Подскажите что необходимо сделать, для решение этой проблемы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone

Comment: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: @Air, Спасибо, очень помогло

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...